# Why my code is giving the error name 'sin' is not defined?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to implement a code for the following function: f(x) = sen(2πx), x ∈ [0, 2], to get the graph of it. But I'm getting the return that the sine is not defined. I'm not quite understanding what I would have to correct. I would be grateful if someone can help me

Code I used:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x): return sin*(2*np.pi*x)  
  
x = np.linspace(0,2)  
plt.plot(x, f(x))    
plt.grid()  
plt.show()
```

This was the only code I thought of to solve this issue, because I thought it would print correctly and without errors

Comment: Either do `import numpy as np` then use `np.sin`, or do `from numpy import sin` then use `sin`. But if you try a mix of both, it won't work.

Comment: @Stef Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the sine function is defined inside numpy, so you should explicitly specify the library where the function is defined:

```
def f(x): return np.sin*(2*np.pi*x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use the `sin` function without import it. You can find the function in the `numpy` package:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*x)  

x = np.linspace(0,2)  
plt.plot(x, f(x))    
plt.grid()  
plt.show()
```

Comment: If OP asks "why my code is giving this error", they expect at the very least an answer of *why* the code gives an error. A different code snippet fails to resolve that very basic question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct ways to get access to function `sin` from module `numpy`:

Either:

```py
from numpy import sin

sin([3,4,5])
# array([ 0.14112001, -0.7568025 , -0.95892427])
```

Or:

```py
import numpy as np

np.sin([3,4,5])
# array([ 0.14112001, -0.7568025 , -0.95892427])
```

You got an error because you tried a mix of both.